# Integrating custom design system based on MUI with a Nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to integrate my custom react component library which is based on MUI and bundled with Rollup to a Nextjs page routers project. I have gone through the MUI documentation for the same which provides "@mui/material-nextjs" package for creating an emotion cache and a utility function for extracting and inserting styles to document head. When trying to export the package from my library, and creating a custom document to update its initial props, I am getting an error that document.getInitialProps is not a function:

```js
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx: DocumentContext) => {   const finalProps = await documentGetInitialProps(ctx);
  return finalProps;
};
```

```js
  19946 |                 enhanceApp: App => plugins.reduce((result, plugin) => plugin.enhanceApp(result), App)
  19947 |             });
> 19948 |             const initialProps = yield document$1.getInitialProps(ctx);
  19949 |             const finalProps = yield plugins.reduce((result, plugin) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { return plugin.resolveProps(yield result); }), Promise.resolve(initialProps));
  19950 |             return finalProps;
  19951 |         });
 ⨯ TypeError: document$1.getInitialProps is not a function
```

Is this an issue with how rollup is bundling my exports?